# Material UI CSS injection order

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, google-chrome-devtools, emotion

I want the order of my styles to be...

1. Styles from the `<CssBaseline>` component.
2. Styles generated by Emotion that Material UI produces.
3. My own custom stylesheet.

Here's a simplified version of how my App component is configured...

```
import { CssBaseline } from "@mui/material";
import { StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import "./styles/main.scss";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <CssBaseline>
      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <Layout></Layout>
      </StyledEngineProvider>
    </CssBaseline>
  );
};
```

Here's the order that it's rendering in the browser...

[image]

I've read [this article](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#css-injection-order) which doesn't seem to address my specific issue of trying to get the CssBaseline component to get applied first.

How do I get them in the order I want? Or perhaps more simply, how do I get it so that the `<CssBasline>` styles get applied first and not last in my case?